# How to prepare datas from an array in order to store entries from index 0 and index 1 and then from index 1 to index 2?

Tags: php, arrays

For a routing application i need some ideas in order to solve the following issues. I have an array with dynamic datas and not constant size. In this array are stored street names, street numbers, telephone number, postalcode and locations...Aftre every entry it exists an identifier called "-END-". At this identifier i want to explode the datas and store in an new separate array. Now i want store in the database the datas from index 0 and index 1, because this is a completey tour. After this saving i want to store the datas from index 1 and index 2, then if exists from index 2 and index 3 and so on.

The content of the array by using var_dump() looks like this:

```
Madtricks:::
Herr Müller:::
ahhvvbe_hh@sdsfsfdsfds.de:::
Brächerwog:::
5:::
10107:::
Hamburgh:::
475454654:::
Sonstiges: Keine Angabe:::
Links oben:::
-END-::: //Here is the end of the complete dataset
Test-Company:::
Herr Mustermann:::
mtest.de@pmail.com:::
Littenweg:::
12:::
10627:::Hamburgh:::
1555444522:::Sonstiges: Keine Angabe::: Keiner:::
-END-::: //Here is the end of the complete dataset
Next Company:::
Frau Schacht:::
ahhvvbe_hh@fgfdhfd.de:::
Hubertusstraße:::
5:::
10107:::
Hamburg:::
475454654:::
Sonstiges: Keine Angabe:::
Links oben:::
-END-::: //Here is the end of the complete dataset
```

I tried some loops but i cant find any way to store the dataset 1 and 2 and then 2 and 3 and so on.

The final result should looks like this: (Short version)

```
function SaveData()
{
 1st save: saveIntoDatabase(Madtricks, Brächerwog, [further datas], Test-Company, Littenweg);
 2nd save: saveIntoDatabase(Test-Company, Littenweg,  [further datas] Next Company, Hubertusstraße);
}
```

At the end i want to have a complete tour in the database from adress one to adress two and then from adress two to adress three and so on. Thanks for any hints.

UPDATE:

I made the following and it seems to work but maybe its not the best solution?

```
$tourData=base64_decode($data['TourData']);
$concat = array();
$explodeAtValueEnd = array();
$explodeAtValueEnd = explode("-END-",$tourData);

for($j=0;$j<count($explodeAtValueEnd);$j++)
{
    $concat[]=$explodeAtValueEnd[$j];
    $concat[]=$explodeAtValueEnd[$j+1];

    if(count($concat)==2)
    {
        $nameStart = $concat[0];
        $nameZiel = $concat[1];
        if(strlen($nameStart) >3 && strlen($nameZiel) >3)
            Save($nameStart, $nameZiel);
        unset($concat);
        unset($explodeAtValueEnd[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: For me it is not really clear what you want to achieve. So each line in the example data is an array entry where `Madtricks:::` is index 0 and `Herr Müller:::` is index 1 etc? And you want to split that array on the value `-END-:::`in separate arrays? Is ::: part of the data? Where do index 0 and index 1 refer to in your question? Perhaps it would be clearer to add the var_dump or var_export itself to the question.

Comment: The example data consits of only one array. Within this array all datas represents one set of addresses and is marked by the value "-END-". The signs":::" are a part of the data. So i could explode at the value "-END-" and for this example i get an array with a size of 3. And this array i want to use to save every set of adress data with index[0] and index[1], index[1] and index[2]....an so on. I will add to my question what i made in addition but i think thats really not a good solution.